# Differential Equation $y^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=e^y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a problem with solving this equation.

I've tried different ways but nothing works.

$$y^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=e^y$$

Comment: Are you solving for a certain variable?

Comment: no, I want the common answer for this equation

Comment: Are you sure it's not dx/dy

Comment: that's what's been given to me

Comment: "I've tried different ways but nothing works." Please be more specific about what you tried.

Comment: I've tried different approaches that I've learned to solve first-order differential equations but nothing gets me near the answer

Answer (score 3):

Notice that L.H.S can be written as an exact differential, i.e:
$$\frac{d}{dy}(xy^2)=e^y$$
$$\implies d(xy^2)=e^ydy$$
Integrating both sides, we get:
$$xy^2=e^y+C$$

Comment: I think this would only be correct if the equation in the OP contained $dx/dy$ rather than $dy/dx$.

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim True, I cannot solve it with dy/dx now that I've noticed.

Answer (score 3):

$y^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}+2xy=e^y$

$y^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^y-2yx$

$(e^y-2yx)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=y^2$

Let $u=\dfrac{e^y}{2y}-x$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{e^y}{2y}-u$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{(y-1)e^y}{2y^2}-\dfrac{du}{dy}$

$\therefore2yu\left(\dfrac{(y-1)e^y}{2y^2}-\dfrac{du}{dy}\right)=y^2$

$\dfrac{(y-1)e^yu}{2y^2}-u\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{y}{2}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{(y-1)e^yu}{2y^2}-\dfrac{y}{2}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $t=\dfrac{e^y}{2y}$ ,

Then $y=-W\left(-\dfrac{1}{2t}\right)$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dy}=\dfrac{(y-1)e^y}{2y^2}\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore\dfrac{(y-1)e^yu}{2y^2}\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{(y-1)e^yu}{2y^2}-\dfrac{y}{2}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=u-\dfrac{y^3}{(y-1)e^y}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}-u=\dfrac{\left(W\left(-\dfrac{1}{2t}\right)\right)^2}{2t\left(W\left(-\dfrac{1}{2t}\right)+1\right)}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for, but I am assuming that you want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, so

$$y^2 \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy=e^y$$

$$y^2 \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=e^y - 2xy$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^y - 2xy}{y^2}$$

Comment: Probably not what OP is asking for

Comment: Well he didnt really say much about what he is looking for. I guess it doesnt hurt to just write this solution out there :)

Comment: I think 'solving' refers to removing the $\frac {dy}{dx}$ term, although I may be wrong :)

Comment: the point is having a equation without dx and dy in the end, that's it